# Where clause based on priority

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider Following table named A:

```
  State City Rank
   S     C    1
  AB     C1   2
   *     C2   3
```

I want to select all columns such that

1. If State is AB return all such rows
2. If condition 1 is not met return all rows with state *. If condition 1 is met don't look on to this condition

As per above example I should get row 2.  I tried several things like

```
select state
     case when a.state = 'AB' then 1
           when a.state = '*'  then 2
      end as priority   from A  where state in  ('AB','*')  order by priority
```

But above query returns more than one rows. I want exact one row which matches above condition.

Please help

EDIT1:

I want to avoid sub queries due to performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select * from A
where state=case
  when exists(select * from A where state='AB') then 'AB'
  else '*'
  end
```

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c693/2) demonstrating the above.

Comment: Well, I don't think you will be able to. There must be a way to determine if at least one row with `state='AB'` exists, in order to direct the condition to the right comparison. So either an `exists` subquery or a `count/group by` one is unaviodable -- unless I'm missing something terribly obvious.

Comment: **@geomagas**, +1, nice clean query to get exactly what the OP was asking for.  I added the SQL Fiddle to further illustrate your answer.